# SQL query in Doctrine2

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

I really need help here, does anyone know how to transform this `SQL` query into a Doctrine2 query using the createQueryBuilder?

`SELECT a.resposta,

(

    SELECT count(r.id)

    FROM car_resultado r2

    LEFT JOIN car_resultado_inquerito ri2 ON r2.id_resultado_inquerito = ri2.id

    WHERE ri2.id_inquerito = 20 AND r2.id_resposta = a.id

    GROUP BY r2.id_pergunta, r2.id_resposta

) as total

FROM car_resposta a

LEFT JOIN car_resultado r ON ( r.id_resposta = a.id )

GROUP BY a.id, r.id_resposta`

I have no idea how to do it, mainly because that nested `SELECT`

Comment: I don't know about doctine, but if doctrine it's coming from PHP and you have here SQL code, how would you convert SQL to Doctrine?, I mean SQL and Doctrine are different.  Another thing can you add to the subquery LIMIT 1, I think you could have a problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you have to create your Entities and Repositories to get the data from your database. But in Doctrine2 is a uncool way. You can execute native SQL.

[Doctrine2 Native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)

If its possible you shouldn't do it and work with the classes but if you have a complicated existing queries you can do it.